# Is it possible to crack VPN handshake?

Tags: vpn

If i connect to VPN, we have *some* handshake to exchange info about how the traffic will be encrypted. If someone(e.g. my ISP) would capture the whole handshake and connection part, is there any way to get *any* info out of it ? For example login info.

Comment: What protocol is your VPN using?

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the protocol used for your VPN - this is not nearly enough information.  If PPTP, yes, likely - PPTP is definitively broken.  If something else, well, it depends.  A well crafted VPN protocol is not susceptible to replay attacks - look up your protocol and see its current status.

Comment: I meant OpenVPN. Probably the most famous. Is it the same mechanism as if i am connecting over HTTPS(SSL/TLS) ?

Comment: @ShinobiUltra OpenVPN (in its most common mode) performs its key exchange over TLS.

Comment: @ShinobiUltra And TLS is not susceptible to replay attacks - each HELLO is responded to with a different random value, which affects all subsequent messages in the handshake, making replay impossible.